# laptop restarts when ethernet cable is plugged in

Tags: windows-7, windows, ethernet

Laptop (Windows 7, Sony Vaio) automatically shuts down, retarts and then after a minute shuts down, restarts etc in an endless cycle when the ethernet cable is plugged in.

When the cable is removed or LAN adapter is disabled, no problem.

The problem still happen in safe mode with networking.

I tried disabling and re-enabling the adapter, deleting and reinstalling the driver, disabling auto restart after crashes, system restore (didn't work), restoring to the last known good configuration.  Nothing helped.

Comment: I assume this doesn't occur when you're on wireless? Try a Windows repair

Comment: Also, do you mean that, if the LAN adapter is disabled you can plug the cable in and it won't restart?

Comment: This sounds like hardware failure on the lan device itself.

Comment: Yes, if the LAN adapter is disabled I can plug the cable in and it will not restart.

Comment: What is Windows repair?  Thank you.

Comment: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html
I Would be checking a system doing something like that with a good virus checker. Or a couple of those (ugg) online virus scanners. Some virus makers have thought it was funny/cute to knock people off the "community" (web) when they were exposed, vulnerable, and just less knowledgable.

Answer (score 0):

This reads like a fundamental driver error.
But to make sure if it's a hardware or a driver failure, you can try a Linux Live-CD (e.g. [Kubuntu](https://kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/)) to test if it's really an error in the Windows driver (because Ubuntu has a different driver).

- If the error persists running Ubuntu, it's a hardware failure.
- If not, it's a Windows driver failure.